# Get first element's attribute in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am writing an automated site backup powershell script.

I have the following xml in an [xml] casted variable obtained from appcmd.exe:

```
<application path="/" applicationPool="komplus.ua-PROD">     
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults />  
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\WEB\PROD\komplus.ua" />       
</application>
<application path="/kb" applicationPool="komplus.ua-PROD" enabledProtocols="http, https">
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults /> 
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\WEB\PROD\komplus.ua\kb" />
</application>
```

The xml is in the variable $xmlInput.

I need to get the value of the physicalPath attribute of VirtualDirectory element in first application element.

I've tried several options, including custom Get-XmlElement functions, but can't seem to get to the value.

Currently I have:

```
 $selectResult = $xmlInput.application.virtualDirectory | Select physicalPath
```

But the $selectResult is null.

Please assist in which parsing is correct to get the value I need.

**Update**

Here is a full function I am using to get the full path:

```
function GetPhysicalPath ([String]$siteName) {


function Get-PipelineInput
{            
    end {
        $inputAsVar = 'Current input is:' + $input
        write-host "##teamcity[message text='$inputAsVar']"

        write-host "##teamcity[message text='About to cast to xml']"
        $xmlInput = [xml]@"<root>$input</root>"@

        write-host "##teamcity[message text='Cast to xml finished.']"                

        $selectResult = $xml.root.Application | Where-Object { $_.path -eq '/' } | ForEach-Object { $_.virtualDirectory.physicalPath }

        write-host "##teamcity[message text='$selectResult']"

        return $selectResult

        #$node = Get-XmlNode -XmlDocument $xmlInput -NodePath "application.virtualDirectory"

        #$nodeAsVar = 'Single node is:' + $node
        #write-host "##teamcity[message text='$nodeAsVar']"
        #if ($node -eq $null) { return $null }

        #return $node.physicalPath
    }
}

$appCmd = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

return & $appCmd list app /site.name:"$siteName" /config | Get-PipelineInput
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml isn't valid. XML requires a root element. If you "xml"-file is missing it, then wrap the file's content inside a root element yourself like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Frode\Desktop -Filter "appcmd*" | ForEach-Object {

    #Wrap "xml" in root element and convert to xml-type
    $xml = [xml]@"
<root>
$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName))
</root>
"@

    #Get first physicalPath
    $xml.root.Application[0].virtualDirectory.physicalPath
}

C:\WEB\PROD\komplus.ua
```

If you have PowerShell 3 or newer, you could replace `$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName))` with the more friendly `$(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw))`. However, `ReadAllText()` is normally faster so I would use it anyways.

If you want the root-application, you should probably search for that instead of guessing that it's the first element. You could try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Frode\Desktop -Filter "appcmd*" | ForEach-Object {

    #Wrap "xml" in root element and convert to xml-type
    $xml = [xml]@"
<root>
$(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw))
</root>
"@

    #Get root app's physicalPath
    $xml.root.Application | Where-Object { $_.path -eq '/' } | ForEach-Object { $_.virtualDirectory.physicalPath }
}
```

If you're getting the xml-content directly from appcmd.exe (stored in a variable), then modify like this:

```
$outputfromappcmd = appcmd.exe something something

#Wrap "xml" in root element and convert to xml-type
$xml = [xml]"<root>$outputfromappcmd </root>"

#Get first physicalPath
$xml.root.Application | Where-Object { $_.path -eq '/' } | ForEach-Object { $_.virtualDirectory.physicalPath }
```

Comment: I've tried your advise. Please see my full function code in the original quesiton's body, I've added it.

Comment: +                 $xmlInput = [xml]@"<root>$input</root>"@
[Step 1/3] +                                    ~
[Step 1/3] No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the 
[Step 1/3] line.

Comment: I am getting the above mentioned error in build output when I am trying your last advise. I think we are almost there, please take a look =)

Comment: You're not using my last advise properly. You can't use a here-string like that. `$xmlinput = [xml]@"` and `"@` need to be their own lines. See how I used it in the first solution, or drop the here-string and use `$xmlinput = [xml]"<root>$input</root>"`

Comment: The catch was not to cast appcmd piplined $input into a variable, but to just use it right away in an xml cast. Thank you @Frode F.